# Set PowerShell Execution Policy for a service account

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, security-policy

I would like to adjust the PowerShell Execution Policy for a service account, i.e. the IIS user (or let alone those new SSIS virtual accounts). However, it looks like you can only adjust the policy system-wide like so

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

or for the current user like so

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Do I look at the wrong place, can this be found in the Registry, or is it a Group Policy?

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: You might be able to rung an interactive PS session for those service accounts and execute `Set-ExecutionPolicy` within their scope.

Comment: I tried that but that would require me to set the password of those accounts manually (and probably would not work for virtual accounts).

Answer (score 1):

As defined in the help files.

> [Execution Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6)
>
> Scope 
>   You can set an execution policy that is
>   effective only in a particular scope. The valid values for Scope are
>   MachinePolicy, UserPolicy, Process, CurrentUser, and LocalMachine.
>   LocalMachine is the default when setting an execution policy. The
>   Scope values are listed in precedence order. The policy that takes
>   precedence is effective in the current session, even if a more
>   restrictive policy was set at a lower level of precedence.
>
> ***MachinePolicy*** Set by a Group Policy for all users of the computer.
>
> ***UserPolicy*** Set by a Group Policy for the current user of the computer.
>
> ***Process*** The Process scope only affects the current PowerShell session.
>   The execution policy is saved in the environment variable
>   $env:PSExecutionPolicyPreference, rather than the registry. When the
>   PowerShell session is closed, the variable and value are deleted.
>
> ***CurrentUser*** The execution policy affects only the current user. It's
>   stored in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry subkey.
>
> ***LocalMachine*** The execution policy affects all users on the current computer. It's
>   stored in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry subkey.

However, enforced Domain-wide GPO's that include ExecutionPolicy settings, will take precedence over anything you set.

Comment: Yes, saw set. So, the implicit answer is: It cannot be done for individual service accounts.

Comment: Not in the way you seem to be wanting to do this. EP per individual account can only be done per PowerShell session, for example I have multiple shortcuts to start in different scopes, because my system -wide setting is set to Restricted. I do this daily but not for service accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer three approaches and there is others in this SO question [Change PS exec policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753917/how-do-you-successfully-change-execution-policy-and-enable-execution-of-powershe)

### Builid Machines

Run it from CMD (or bash)

```
PowerShell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "X:\Jenkins\path to your file\your file.ps1"
```

or

```
PowerShell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File ".\your file.ps1"
```

or

```
PowerShell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned "& '.\your file.ps1'"
```

I think other approaches are good but kinda fragile, except you are using a docker.

### Using the Windows Startup feature to override a Domain Controller group policies

It uses coupe of scripts, CMD and PowerShell - [description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753917/how-do-you-successfully-change-execution-policy-and-enable-execution-of-powershe/34889926#34889926)

### LocalMachine policy isn't enabled

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27753927/390940)

[image: Run as administrator]
[image: Adds Group Policy Object Editor]

In the left sidebar
**Local Computer Policy**
**Computer Configuration**
**Administrative Templates**
**Windows Components**
**Windows PowerShell**
and double-click **Turn on Script Execution**

[image]

Comment: Thanks but how does this answer my question? I wanted to adjust the PowerShell Execution Policy for a service account, not the entire machine or the DC.