# In Powershell, How to set execution policy for another non-admin user (as admin)?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-registry, group-policy

the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy` has a parameter `-Scope` which only has 5 categories:

```
  MachinePolicy       
  UserPolicy       
  Process       
  CurrentUser    
  LocalMachine
```

It appears to have no way to specify a user.

As an administrator, how to set execution policy for another user?

There is a similar question, however it's also unsolved.
[Set PowerShell Execution Policy for a service account](https://superuser.com/questions/1423390/set-powershell-execution-policy-for-a-service-account)

note that there might be a way to create group policy object for another user in registry, but I'm still experimenting on this.

Comment: Why can’t you simply set it once for the entire machine?

Comment: @Ramhound it's against the ideal security configuration, for example I may want to have some non-admin users to have execution policy of AllSigned while admins have unrestricted.

Comment: @Sajuuk Are you wanting to allow the user to be able to run any script once you elevate it, or are you doing this to ensure a specific script runs as the user while they are logged onto a machine? I have some ideas but it might depend on what you are ultimately trying to accomplish before I can make a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

ExecutionPolicy set at the machine-level has no effect on the EP set at other levels, hence the different policies. ExecutionPolicy set at any other level, has no effect on the machine EP. EP's are a 1:1 thing, they are all independent of each other.

I do this all day long for my team and specific folks and I've shown other customers I support how to do this. My enforced GPO has set EP to restricted at the machine level, but RemoteSigned for the target user accounts and those are set at the user or process level at RemoteSigned.

The machine-level GPO is a 1:1 thing. The user EP, is set via a shortcut pushed to the target user machines. It has a hotkey shortcut assigned as well as pinned to the taskbar in the 6th position. If the user starts the normal PowerShell shortcut, running scripts are blocked. Using the customized user shortcut, they are not.

EP's do not in any way block users from running PowerShell code. Open any PS code in the ISE/VSCode, etc, select all and hit run and it will work as expected. EP, prevents the user from accidentally running scripts. MS has never said the EP is a security boundary/controller, as a point of note they specifically state that it is not.

There are literally dozens of ways to bypass EP settings. [The howTo's are all over the web](https://www.bing.com/search?q=ways%20to%20bypass%20execution%20policy&form=ANSPH1&refig=177f0115f11c4706a9ec7e06c7451b38&sp=-1&pq=ways%20to%20bypass%20execution%20policy&sc=1-31&qs=n&sk=&cvid=177f0115f11c4706a9ec7e06c7451b38), even from [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ken_brumfield/simple-way-to-temporarily-bypass-powershell-execution-policy).

> [15 Ways to Bypass the PowerShell Execution Policy](https://theknowledgehound.home.blog/2020/03/02/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/)
>
> [Bypass the PowerShell Execution Policy](https://9to5it.com/bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/)

One can write there own Powershell host, because 
 powershell.exe/pwsh.exe/powershell_ise.exe is not PowerShell, they are only PowerShell host that run PowerShell code.

Lots of these alternate hosts exist, again all over the web.

MSDN has a [section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) devoted to writing a PowerShell host in the [PowerShell SDK documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is a nice starting point.

Other articles on custom hosts:

http://powershellstation.com/2009/10/12/writing-your-own-powershell-hosting-app-part-1-introduction

http://dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/02/how-to-host-powershell-in-a-wpf-application/

http://powershellstation.com/2009/10/12/writing-your-own-powershell-hosting-app-part-1-introduction

http://code.google.com/p/farnet/wiki/PowerShellFar

http://poshconsole.codeplex.com

http://studioshell.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks for the security boundary and other excellent info, however regarding my question, your part of the answer seem to be unverifiable.  "ExcuationPolcy set at the machine-level has no effect on the EP set at other levels", when I tested it, standard user cannot override machine wide EP. using Set-ExecutionPolicy *** -scope CurrentUser.

Comment: You misunderstood, my statement then. Setting the EP and any other level does not impact the setting at another level. Thought the EP is not a security boundary, it is an operational boundary. Again, I reinforce, I do this every day.  I do not what my machine operational state to change, and thus why the two EP policy approach. The user should have no reason/privilege to change the machine policy. Again, EP is a 1:1 thing.